# Elasticsearch sniffer importance

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm a little lost regarding the new elasticsearch rest client (5.x) and the importance of a sniffer. I'm using elasticsearch as a service, so basically all I have is one url (x-pack, load balancer etc). This url "hides" three nodes. My question is, do I need to enable sniffing? If yes, what exactly will happen, since the nodes are not exposed directly.

Version: elasticsearch 5.3.1 (server, client, sniffer)

Comment: Yes you are correct. I'm not really after an answer for the exception, just to give some context, but I'll remove it. Thank you

Comment: As far as I understand, sniffing is there to reconnect the nodes that have failed or check if any new nodes are installed withing a time interval. So, whether or not you need sniffing entirely depends on whether you want that behavior in your system.

Comment: Yes, but since the nodes are not exposed, is this relevant when using elasticsearch as a service?

Comment: I'd expect it to be: that is internal structure management procedure, which is generally hidden from your client anyway. But let's see if someone with actual experience has an answer.